# sed use to replace string 2 lines after matching pattern in AIX 6.1

Tags: sed, aix

I try to replace a character, 2 lines after matching pattern. For this, I'm using this code:

```
sed '/some_pattern/{N;N;s/word1/word2/}' /etc/filesystems > /etc/filesystems.tmp && mv -f /etc/filesystems.tmp /etc/filesystems
```

I tested this command and confirmed it's working fine on Linux. However, when I use it in AIX, I receive an error message like:

```
sed: Function /some_pattern/{N;N;s/word1/word2/} cannot be parsed.
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AIX sed needs each command on a separate line.
See [man page](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.cmds5/sed.htm)
and try

```
sed '/some_pattern/{
 N
 N
 s/word1/word2/
}'
```

Answer (score -1):

This works for me

```
sed '/some_pattern/{N;N;s/word1/word2/;}'
```

Comment: Of course it does, since you're using GNU `sed`.  GNU `sed` is not available on AIX unless it's installed separately.